# Working local with one database

Tags: database, git

We are working with GIT while development but keep sending each other database exports.
I would like to use one database on a development server (as suggested to be the easiest solution on [Keeping WP database synced across multiple developers using git](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52725/keeping-wp-database-synced-across-multiple-developers-using-git))

But WP saves saves the domainname and while working local, for example localhost/project.
All urls still point to dev.domain.com/

Can we overcome this problem or should we try another approach?

Comment: You are all in the same location? Have access to a common server? Then you should just use that as the server name. In my office we have a MAMP server running, and just access it by it's local IP: 192.168.192.blah:8888/project-name. Although, that is also where all the files are...

Comment: That's the problem, everybody has his/her own copy of the files and work on their own machine.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a staging database on an online host and connect remotely from your various local dev environments. Might get a little confusing sharing 1 DB between many installs though.