# Development environment

Tags: customization, deployment, development-strategy

We have an internal project where two developers work together, each one on each local environment and they integrate their work on a small shared server. I've realized that whenever someone does something (e.g., installing a new plugin), they need to agree how the sync across the three environments, usually manually using plugins such as [Database Sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/database-sync/).

For those who come from more established environment, I found such development workflow very ineffective. Normally we based on git all our development workflows: when you push, unit and integration tests run, and if they're successful they get deployed on the integration server (re-creating the database or whatever is needed). So I wonder how people normally do it developing for WordPress.

Thanks in advance. I really appreciate all comments to this respect.

Comment: There already have been a couple of very similar questions. Have you read for example http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52725/keeping-wp-database-synced-across-multiple-developers-using-git?rq=1 Also could you try to be more specific as this is a pretty broad question.